# Make super view's height flexible based on child view's aspect ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout, autolayout

Attached image shows Whatever I want..

[image]

From image, you can see that B and C are subviews of A (Dark blue border indicated view A). B is having aspect ratio (B's height would be based on its width). C will have fixed height.

I want such a combination of constraints so that, height of A should be based their subview's calculation.

Comment: Can u elaborate Bhavin ?

Comment: C is having top space to B. B don't has bottom pin

Comment: Image just shows what I want, I haven't gave any constraints yet..

Comment: Yes, for aspect ratio of A, but it is useless. I need aspect ration for B, but main issue is how to define height of A (parent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what constraints you need:

For View A:

[image]

For View B:

[image]

For View C:

[image]

Comment: This works like a charm, upvoted ! As this is the first answer, I am going to accept it. Auto-layout is really great..

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Below are the constraints set for view hieararchy:

[image]

For View A :

[image]

For View B :

[image]

For View C:

[image]

Also you can set View B's constraint like this way if you don't want square always:

[image]

Comment: Bhadresh, your answer is what I needed, upvoted. As the other user has posted answer very first, I am going to accept it...

Answer (score 1):

You constraints should be like,

View A,

`leading, Trailing, Top`

View B,

`leading, trailing, top, bottom and aspect ratio`

View C,

`leading, trailing, bottom and fix height`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: In above answer there is a `top constraint` for view C. Is should be not there. it will create ambiguity. and aspect ratio doesn't require 1 : 1. It will automatically set as per view's size in canvas.

Comment: If we set aspect ratio 1 : 1 then view B will get `square shape` always!!

Comment: Yes, bottom constraint automatically became C's top but it shouldn't mentioned in answer, because less familiar person with autolayout try to set this again. and as per image shown in question aspect ratio must not equal to `1 : 1`. there is no need to mention ratio in answer because it is automatically decided as per view's size in interface builder.

Comment: yeah, I am not also arguing but i have tried to post answer with more perfection. Nothing else man!